# Why is only the first React component rendering in my multi-page in Django app?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I am trying to render a secondary component to a different URL in my React frontend of my Django app. The URLs seem to be set up correctly, as the page title is changing accordingly and no errors are thrown, but the page itself is blank. My components are being loaded by importing in `index.js` in the components directory.

```
#index.js
import App from './components/App';
import Viz from './components/Viz';
```

```
#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('viz/', views.getviz)
]
```

For the simplicity of testing, I made the components a copy so I know it works.

```
// App.js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Header from './layout/Header';
import Dashboard from './splits/Dashboard';
import Alerts from './layout/Alerts';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert';
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic';

import store from '../store';

//Alert Options
const alertOptions = {
    timeout: 3000,
    position: 'bottom center'
}

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
                    <Fragment>
                        <Header />
                        <Alerts />
                        <div className="container">
                            <Dashboard />
                        </div>
                    </Fragment>
                </AlertProvider>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

The only difference with the other file is the replacement of the component name and element id to change from `App/app` -> `Viz/viz` respectively. I am using this as my `index.html`, with only the element ID switched:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>viz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I realised that **only** the component **placed first** in the `index.js` is being loaded (I tried switching them round which confirmed it), so I imagine there is something additional I need to do when loading multiple components vs. one - but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Do `./components/{App,Viz}` both have `ReactDOM.render`? If so, that's why.  Both are being ran on load, which explains why the first shows. I would guess the browser inspector could be showing an error too.

Comment: You would know best because it's your project, but generally speaking, you can use [webpack-bundle-tracker](https://github.com/django-webpack/webpack-bundle-tracker) and configure separate webpack [entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) for each django route (e.g. `''` -> `app` and `/viz` -> `viz`). Another popular option is a catch-all django route, e.g. `re_path(r'^(?P<path>.*)/$', views.spa)` and a frontend router like [react router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6) to serve the components.

Comment: @TonyN In response to the first comment - looks like this is being thrown: `Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: @TonyN I am trying to implement the multiple entry point method you highlighted above, specifically referring to the [multi page application](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application) section. I am not really sure how to rework the existing components/structure to link this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice from @TonyN's comments, I managed to get [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/) method working well.

I reorganised `App.js` to be the home of the Router and brought my components in as follows:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import UploadPage from './UploadPage';
import Viz from './Viz';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' element={ <UploadPage />} />
                <Route exact path='/viz' element={ <Viz /> } />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

This left me with only one render. Only other update to make was urls on django side:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('viz', views.index)
]
```

I now understand this interaction a bit better, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

This [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/YEmjBEDyVSY?t=1049) also helped bring it to life for me, so I'll leave that here too.